# Insomnia same request with different data

Tags: api, rest, unit-testing, insomnia

I'am trying to write unit tests for each one of my requests in insomnia.
Is there a way to access the request in javascript and modify the body/query params? I want to test the different edge cases.

Are the insomnia js functions documented anywhere?

[image]

Comment: I was sneaking into the code from the Insomnia class and it has a activeEnvironmentId parameter but it's not used anywhere, if this parameter were used to make the api request would be possible to create a body based on the environment like in Postman do.

https://www.postman.com/postman/workspace/postman-answers/documentation/9215231-b9133e48-73c3-4aa4-b189-e038ee4c5e00